# SncRedisBundle not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: symfony, redis, symfony-2.6

```
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: redis://localhost
    session:
        client: session
        prefix: session_
        use_as_default: true
```

The above is my current snc_redis config in config.yml
I added defined snc_redis as my session handler id by doing the following:

```
framework:
    ...
    session:
        handler_id: snc_redis.session.handler
```

The error I get:

```
  The service definition "snc_redis.session_client" does not exist.
```

and when I delete the line `client: session`, it still fails:

```
The child node "client" at path "snc_redis.session" must be configured.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your config.yml file, try to add this:

```
# config.yml
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: redis://%redis_address%
            logging: %kernel.debug%
        session:
            type: predis
            alias: session
            dsn: redis://%redis_address%/1
            logging: true
    session:
        client: session
        prefix: %project_name%
```

This will set 2 clients, default and cache. You could use default to handle caching for data, and `session` so that the session stuff is handled. 
If you only have 1 shard, you could just remove the session client (`snc_redis.clients.session`), and then set the `snc_redis.session.client` to `default`

Regarding the framework part, try this:

```
framework:
    ...
    session: ~
```

The SncRedisBundle will then manage sessions for you based on the first configuration. The second configuration just tells Symfony to keep defaulting.

Tell me if it works or not, and I'll edit accordingly :)

Comment: `use_as_default: true` is no longer a valid configuration? `Unrecognized option "use_as_default" under "snc_redis.session"`

Comment: @Kal Yep, since this commit (https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle/commit/06f7944f9472e5b605f642efda63db900f1a7307), it is now removed! Will edit my post, thanks ;-)

Comment: Thanks :) Trying to get doctrine to save entities to cache rather than mysql DB.